# Toggle additional panes within the vscode sidebar

Tags: visual-studio-code

So before, on my windows machine I used to have additional options in the Source Control tab in vscode. Now I've switched to Mac, and I don't see those options, worse still, I just can't find how to turn them on. There used to be options like commits, stashes etc., towards the bottom of the page.

I'd really like them back :(

[image]

Comment: do you have any git extension installed like git lens?

Comment: No the point isn't just the source control pane, each tab in the sidebar has additional panes, and I want to know how to turn them on. Like the Folder tab has an outline option on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You should install Git Lens extension in VS Code for source control panel.